# Reading Text File, Extracting Strings, Joining them In a List

Tags: python

i am trying to read a text file with these binary files and only get the text betwen the d,d,c of the strings. Once i get that value I need to put them together in a list of lists. I am however having a difficult time because when i print A below...the strings go in different lines. When I print micr_ocr_dat then i get a list of elements but duplicated. See output examples below.

input.txt

```
d01234567d1929739798c02798 x\00x\00 x\00x\00           d01234567d1929739798c02798 
d7827688d389137c3311    x\00x\00 x\00x\00                   d7827688d12233333c3311
```

notice in this output it duplicates each string...

output when printing micr_ocr_dat:

```
['d01234567d1929739798c02798' ,'d01234567d1929739798c02798']
['d01234567d1929739798c02798' ,'d01234567d1929739798c02798']
['d7827688d389137c3311', 'd7827688d389137c3311']
['d7827688d12233333c3311','d7827688d12233333c3311']
```

take close look at second element which is getting the second line of my text file and putting them together in a list and not duplicating them like in the outcome above..

expected output

[ ['d01234567d1929739798c02798' ,'d01234567d1929739798c02798'],
['d7827688d389137c3311','d7827688d12233333c3311']]

code:

```
            with open(fp, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as in_file:
                data = in_file.readlines()
                print(fp)
                for row in data:
                    micr_ocr_line = re.findall(r'd[^d]*d[^d]*c[0-9]+|d[^d]*d[^d]*c\s+[0-9]+', row)
                    micr_ocr_dat_l.append(micr_ocr_line)
                    for r in micr_ocr_line:
                        rmve_spcl_char = re.sub (r'([^a-zA-Z-0-9]+?)', '', r)
                        rmve_spcl_char = re.sub(r'(c\d{4,}).*', r'\1', rmve_spcl_char).strip()
                        a = [l for l in rmve_spcl_char.split('\n')]
                        for previous, current in zip(a, a[::1]):
                            micr_ocr_dat = [previous, current]
                            print(micr_ocr_dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to split the text into words, keep only those matching a certain pattern and then split those words using `re.split()`

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("^([dc][0-9]+)+$")

with open('filename', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as in_file:
    data = in_file.read()

# Split text into words
data = data.split()

final_data = []
for word in data:
    # Check if the word only contains numbers or the letters c and d
    if pattern.match(word):
        # Cut the word at each letter c or d
        values = re.split('[cd]', word)
        final_data.append(values[1:])

print(final_data)
```

Output:

```
[
    ['01234567', '1929739798', '02798'], 
    ['01234567', '1929739798', '02798'], 
    ['7827688', '389137', '3311'], 
    ['7827688', '12233333', '3311']
]
```

---

**EDIT**

By separating the text following the line breaks, we can process the data line by line and obtain a list with the values ​​separated according to the lines.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("^([dc][0-9]+)+$")

with open('filename', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as in_file:
    data = in_file.read()

# Split text into lines
data = data.split("\n")

final_data = []
for line in data:
    # Split line into words
    line = line.split()

    line_data = []
    for word in line:
        # Check if the word only contains numbers or the letters c and d
        if pattern.match(word):
            # Cut the word at each letter c or d
            values = re.split('[cd]', word)
            line_data.append(values[1:])
    final_data.append(line_data)
print(final_data)
```

Output:

```
[
    [
        ['01234567', '1929739798', '02798'],
        ['01234567', '1929739798', '02798']
    ],
    [
        ['7827688', '389137', '3311'],
        ['7827688', '12233333', '3311']
    ]
]
```

The same using list comprehension:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("^([dc][0-9]+)+$")

with open('xml_data.xml', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as in_file:
    final_data = [[re.split('[cd]', word)[1:] for word in lines.split() if pattern.match(word)] for lines in in_file.read().split("\n")]
print(final_data)
```

Comment: This was very helpful because i like the format you put it in. However, maybe i explained the question wrong but I need to have them evenly in one list like this .[ [['01234567', '1929739798', '02798'], ,['01234567', '1929739798', '02798'], [ ['7827688', '389137', '3311'], ['7827688', '12233333', '3311'] ]

Comment: @ajburnett34 If I understood correctly, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Regex split applied on each relevant string, simple yet short and efficient.

```
import re

with open('data.dat', 'r') as f:
    data = [re.split(r'd|c', x)[1:] for x in f.read().split() if '\\' not in x] 
    
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[['01234567', '1929739798', '02798'], ['01234567', '1929739798', '02798'], ['7827688', '389137', '3311'], ['7827688', '12233333', '3311']]
```